# Deploying rest webservices in unlimited gb web host

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

We are trying to deploy java restful webservies, which we have implemented using jersey, in unlimitedgb.com webhost. Which provides java7 and tomcat7.

When we had a chat with the technical support team of unlimitedgb, they replied saying "Sorry we are not providing support for JERSEY in java private JVM".

In our local system which consists of java7 and tomcat7, it works fine.

As per my knowledge as jersey provides api's for restful webservice development, so there must not be any dependency on the server or server's architecture or may be some other internals. So jersey must work with java 1.6 and above.

But when I got reply from the technical support team that they don't support jersey I was really confused and started thinking if there is really any dependency of jersey on server or server architecture.

I feel the support team is not having any technical details about jersey.

I have not purchased the web host yet.

Please help me with the technical details so that I can go ahead in purchasing the web host.

Comment: This is how support operations work. They just won't help with any issues that might come up with jersey. It's on you to take the risk... of course, the same applies for your own codebase hosted on unlimitedgb.com. Try to perform a proof of concept before signing anything...

Comment: I don't see a question here...  if it doesn't work, specify what does work and what doesn't, if there are exceptions, specify them, if some of the requests don't go through (PUT/DELETE) specify that, etc.
Can't help you if you don't give enough information...

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem , please let me know whether java 7 is sufficient for JERSEY ? if java 7 is the only need for jersey , I can go ahead for server upgrade.

Comment: @Gokul: Try and deploy your war on Jelastic for free. If it works with Tomcat 7 and appropriate version, it will work with unlimitedgb.com.

Comment: It would be better if you don't use UnlimitedGB account. They provide pathetic service. None of the customer service numbers are valid. Chat support will put you on long queues. All the review online is fake. I have used their service once. I had a horrible time. Their shared servers only have tomcat5. No support for tomcat7. This is the reason your war does not function there. Better move on to open-shift. Its free you can try out there.  What money you have paid UnlimitedGB they never repay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how much this would help but I used [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/) and was able to deploy the war and host Jersey APIs without any support.
So, I am pretty confident with your own private VPS hosting, you should be able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

When support says, 'we don't support that', what they mean is, we won't answer your questions about that topic.

Jersey should be completely fine in that environment, however, you should write a suite of tests, so that when you change JVM you'll be notified of strange failures due to differences in the JVM.  [Testing jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)

If you want a completely Java EE-container-free rest environment, check out [RestExpress](https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress)

Comment: I already have a account in unlimitedgb which has java1.5, but later on when I started developing webservices with jersey I came to know that it is requires java 1.6 or later versions. So I came to know that I have to upgrade my server to java7, but before upgrading I wanted to get more details about it instead of paying and incurring loss.

Comment: Whether Java7 is sufficient for jersey or not??

Comment: Yes, I have developed jersey with java 7, however, it is free to test that so I would recommend you download the jdk, write some tests, and prove it to yourself.

Comment: I already mentioned in my post that it is working fine in my local tomcat server. But I just wanted to confirm that it works fine in web host as well. Please let me know if only java7 is enough for jersey. Thats what I wanted to confirm.